# C++ - how to implement templated member function outside a templated class

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<int N>
class myClass
{
    template<typename T>
    void myFunction();
};

template<typename T>
void myClass<int N>::myFunction() {} // doesn't work, nor do many other combinations!
```

Hi,

Is it possible to achieve the above? I can implement myFunction in the class definition no problem. If so what would the syntax be? GCC 4.2 tells me:

> missing '>' to terminate the template argument list

thanks for your help

Comment: could your problem be the template<int N>? it should be template<typename T> no?

Comment: @Colin:  It is a nontype template parameter.

Answer (score 18):

You are looking for:

```
template <int N>
template <typename T> 
void myClass<N>::myFunction() {}
```

You need one `template` for the class template and one for the member function template.

Answer (score 4):

```
template<int N> template<typename T>
void myClass<N>::myFunction() {}
```