# How to avoid repeating the whole class template when only one member specialization is needed

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Suppose you have:

```
template<class T>
class A {
  template<class T1> 
  void foo(const T1& t1) {}

  //
  // Lots of other definitions (all templated)
  // 
};
```

and you would like to specialize `foo(const T1&)` but only for a specialized `A<bool>`. Like this:

```
template<>
class A<bool> {
  template<class T1> 
  void foo(const T1& t1) {
    // Code for specialized A<boo>::foo
  }

  //
  // Repeating the former definitions, how to avoid this ??
  // 
};
```

But to get this to work I have to duplicate all the code that is defined in the class template `class A` and include it again in `class A<bool>`.

I tried to define only the member specialization:

```
template<>
void A<bool>::template<class T1> foo(const T1&) {}
```

Neither does this work:

```
template <class T1> void A<bool>::foo(const T1&) {}
```

But the compiler doesn't like it.
What's the way to deal with this code duplication?

Comment: Seems you are wrong about the syntax. `error: prototype for ‘void A<bool>::foo(const T1&)’ does not match any in class ‘A<bool>’`

Comment: a good question like that with just my up vote, sad...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Syntax? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833349/c-how-to-implement-templated-member-function-outside-a-templated-class). Try:

```
template<>
template<typename T1>
void A<bool>::foo(const T1&){}
```

You certainly don't need to copy the whole class template.

Comment: Cool! Seems I can never remember the syntax for this

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a function and a class template, then define a couple of typedefs:

```
template<class T, class TArg> 
class A 
{   
    void foo(const TArg& arg) {}

    // Lots of other definitions (all templated)
};

typedef A<MyType, MyType> NormalClass;
typedef A<MyType, bool>   BoolClass;
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not an option. At instantiation time of `A` I have no knowledge on what type `foo` will be used. Sorry

Comment: You mean you don't know at compile time the type or at runtime?